# Em quais situações perdemos pontos de reputação?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Os pontos que ganhamos pela atuação nos sites do SE são:
+10 pergunta votada a favor; +10 resposta votada a favor; +15 a resposta foi aceita; e +2 edição aprovada, se você tiver menos que 2000 pontos de reputação.

Não localizei no [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do SOpt onde fala sobre os pontos negativos.

Em quais situações perdemos pontos de reputação?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Você **ganha** reputação quando:

- a pergunta recebe votos a favor: +10
- a resposta recebe votos a favor: +10
- a resposta é marcada como “aceita”: +15 (+2 para quem aceitou)
- uma edição sugerida é aceita: +2 (até um total de +1000 por usuário)
- sua resposta recebeu uma gratificação: +quantidade total da gratificação
- uma de suas respostas recebeu uma gratificação automaticamente: +1/2 da quantidade da gratificação
- bônus de associação no site: +100 em cada site (recebida no máximo uma vez por site)

Você **perde** reputação quando:

- sua pergunta recebe votos contra: −2
- sua resposta recebe votos contra: −2
- você vota contra uma resposta: −1
- você coloca uma gratificação em uma pergunta: −quantidade total da gratificação
- uma de suas publicações recebe 6 sinalizações como spam ou ofensiva:−100
- Quando um usuário é deletado ou solicita que a conta seja removida você também perde. (Referente aos *upvotes* recebido desse usuário)

Retirado da central de ajuda:  [O que é reputação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Tenho ideia de já ter visto esta resposta no meta.

Comment: Eu estava procurando.. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3866 
E fui eu que respondi. kkkk

Comment: Quando um usuário é deletado ou solicita que a conta seja removida você também perde.

Comment: Não sabia. Já add na resposta. Obrigado @rray :)

Comment: A aceitação pode ser desfeita, daí perde 15 pontos. Assim como os votos tb podem ser retirados, seja dentro do tempo limite (não me lembro quanto é), ou após sua publicação ter sido editada.

Comment: [Evento de reputação: “O usuário foi removido”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1059/91), 

[essa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1605/91) e [esse comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4129/perda-de-pontos-por-usu%C3%A1rio-removido-tem-prazo-de-validade#comment11542_4129)

Comment: ainda está valendo isso de -1 ao votar contra uma resposta? já votei contra e pelo que percebi não perdi reputação por isso