# Votar negativamente em uma resposta ainda tira um ponto de reputação?

Tags: bug, voto-contra, votos, reputação

[Em quais situações perdemos pontos de reputação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4489/em-quais-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-perdemos-pontos-de-reputa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/4490#4490) diz que:

> você vota contra uma resposta: −1

Porém não tenho percebido perda de reputação por ter votado contra respostas. Isso foi mudado?

Edit:

Para ilustrar, meu histórico de reputação sem perdas, sendo que votei contra respostas recentemente. Não que eu esteja reclamando por não perder reputação kk só queria entender isso mesmo.

[image: imagem para ilustrar]

Comment: Aqui no meta, nunca tirou. No site principal, está tirando sim, o mesmo de sempre.

Comment: Leila vai em participação e entra na Aba de Votos: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/42945/leila?tab=votes ai vc confere onde votou contra. Depois vai na Aba reputação e confere se as informações bate... De qq forma hj percebi certa "instabilidade" no site, pode ser que haja um delay até debitar seus pontos ...

Comment: já aconteceu de um dar um *downvote* e não computar, não sei qual situação, se é o primeiro voto contra ou não, mas já aconteceu comigo

Comment: Vejo que votaste contra uma resposta que depois foi apagada — tirando isso, nada de votos contra respostas que fossem causar a perda de reputação... é possível que tenha demorado um bocado a aparecer no separador de reputação e que seja isso que causa a confusão?

Comment: Pelo que o @JNat disse, acho que o que ocorreu foi que você negativou e o autor apagou a resposta em seguida, em um intervalo de tempo curto. As vezes acontece de demorar uns 4min pro downvote ser registrado ou restaurado na reputação.

Comment: Após algum tempo reparando como o sistema estava se portando conforme foi questionado no post, notei que quando eu voto contra não esta sendo computado a perda dos votos, isso pode ver visto na [aba de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/noobsaibot?tab=reputation) e na [aba de votos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/noobsaibot?tab=votes) em meu perfil.